# Other answer is better than my answer; I am also the asker

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

What is the proper way to handle when my answer on a question is (by far) the leading vote getter, but someone else's answer is better?
Improve my answer by including parts of theirs? Give them credit by name in my revised answer?
I already up voted their answer weeks ago, but the score is 12 votes me, 1 vote them.
As another wrinkle, I am both asker and accepted answerer of this question, so another possibility is I can switch the checkmark to their answer.

(The specific question is: [How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from/10416799))

Comment: You could award that answer a bounty perhaps...

Comment: If the other answer is better than yours as in 'more correct' then you should mark it as the accepted answer, possibly editing the reason for accepting the other answer into your own answer .

Comment: I'd think changing the accepted answer to the better one would be better.

Answer (score 17):

The proper way is to do exactly what you would with any question you asked. You accept the answer that solves the question best. I have a self-answer where my answer has a lot more votes than the other, better, answer. I accepted the other user's answer and because it's at the top the situation has been gradually correcting itself as it gets more upvotes.

If you feel like you're being unfair you can also award a bounty; but, using parts of their answer in your own, however attributed, is not the best way to rectify that unfairness.

Accept the better answer and let the internetz decide.

Comment: Exactly.  Moreover, it's not uncommon for the *correct answer* (whether accepted or not) to have a lower score.

Comment: I like part of my answer better (the part about COALESCE), but the "core" part was answered better by the other (on what is in most use scenarios just a technicality). I'd like to just copy that person's SQL code but leave my commentary, in a way that is fair.

Answer (score 3):

You can take multiple actions, depending on your point of view.

As the *asker*, you should accept the best answer. If you accept an answer, and later a better one comes along, then change the accepted answer to the new one.

As an *answerer*, if you see a better answer than yours, you can upvote the other answer.

As *asker*, *answerer*, or *non-participant*, you can reward a really good answer by offering a bounty.

In your case, if you wish, you can do all of the above.

Answer (score 2):

You mention in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198694/other-answer-is-better-than-my-answer-i-am-also-the-asker#comment630165_198696) comment that the **core** part of the question is answered better in the other response.  That shouldn't leave any ambiguity regarding what you should be doing.  If I were you, I'd mark the other answer accepted and improve the other one or add a note in my answer referring to the other one.